# Install python package zipline on cloud 9 environment Support workspace python

Tags: python, ubuntu, c9.io

I am trying to install python on the cloud 9 environment.

I simply did below, from the [installation tutorial](http://www.zipline.io/install.html):

```
pip install zipline
```

However, I get:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/zipline
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log
```

My full log looks like the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Tue Sep 13 06:28:52 2016
Downloading/unpacking zipline
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/
  URLs to search for versions for zipline:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/06/8e/8355df80f313706418ee9db3521c6f0578426d92b6dcddf396d58c4de2e6/zipline-1.0.2.tar.gz#md5=4c7958ad131ebbeeec7d4399bdeff12b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 1.0.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/17/d3/8c58193ec8052d86ff67c00a285a01f646d3d53106844716090c22bba15e/zipline-0.6.0.tar.gz#md5=75d818c291df133946bb15a1b08ae0d8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.6.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/1f/8c/55ea3687c717bc532753860196222f12717201719625d043448ea94f4ff6/zipline-0.5.10.tar.gz#md5=48f394a5ea83848642d879cbeaba8342 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.10
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/22/4a/affbfd183fa4133d13ecebc069bf9887c7755e531175384b57879daecfe2/zipline-0.8.3.tar.gz#md5=042ffcee614d2279add9a1bfd27a33cf (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.8.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/32/29/27e8b5963f1a366c95999ae420c0221f94c3622b69af02f51f7c8b57f086/zipline-0.7.0.tar.gz#md5=62d45c3c0d9a624e787b7e413937f7b4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.7.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/46/84/4e00850f8cd2809b2630348d19d1ccb18959be0d82907cef5413fef6436b/zipline-0.5.9.tar.gz#md5=b8a983ba23b0c7d4ab18a59af9055ab6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.9
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/48/fa/d7dc2e7aca9574b3e06c2d105bb268b85b54633ae8580afe4dd8d607e4be/zipline-0.5.3.tar.gz#md5=e0809b60dc3775868f35ca56d6801f62 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/51/12/9e062af374e826d13e01a705b8ce9532e954d24694cf807fc699fc0978b2/zipline-0.8.1.tar.gz#md5=39a01cc0b79927122abf9f0a9aa9361d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.8.1
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/60/87/7d6d6bd43af11482551eb17cde392b034d7f9d5f43be6f805be51b7bef27/zipline-0.8.3-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=164b2ecae2d6debba9755f6cfa69633f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/76/b7/c420885e7f7b7a664797674c85886a608ae441ae9a45631f9d997ad6392c/zipline-0.5.0.tar.gz#md5=a7cc9112ef0d028768bb80e05f4ce2b4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.0
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/7c/c5/ad47e2ec20b9fd9e907d5e01d448c9e7dbf82b3068301566baf0c628acf9/zipline-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=c455dc96d1b409b7592ed4f7db193429 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/7e/51/cb0336444aeb679cda1aabb6d7c264c1ae8562488503728ee0b23a5101ce/zipline-0.5.5.tar.gz#md5=dca0bb54cfe6ec7c92340e30d8f07469 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.5
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/82/2e/024769455739b6da65ccaa99fdb668acebf614e1db4e241bb4a1117efdda/zipline-0.8.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=69bc977edb5b51e5411d04b816c00c56 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/89/4b/c954275b6a6582c10b6e0ef80d7fe9486e269a26338b42c99795639a46d8/zipline-0.5.6.tar.gz#md5=ab0c71f227e63c61499237b0023964df (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/95/9e/98e2f815f3dd4e8f49b48431f4fc9ff8336270a9c77f5da147cf05b346e1/zipline-0.7.0rc1.tar.gz#md5=5963340584c1bddd446c09bfbbedd38c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.7.0rc1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/97/cf/75e5a64093facaf990baee15eaa2cec4bb204b73cc9aa16d2dbc020591f6/zipline-0.8.4.tar.gz#md5=b385dfee59a0b0408a8dcaae7c4c1d0e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.8.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/9a/aa/5c71f400aba2586619f43b577c99c571f45cc06db3674abc063d109db018/zipline-0.5.7.tar.gz#md5=1fd26989fe73eeb4ad0bb3f997311717 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/a9/5a/5b716619d4bf9b0424ff9f975f8e4bc28641b0f4ffaa57a455722bf60cff/zipline-0.5.4.tar.gz#md5=98e873cb49bbf397b4ca17f48432a9e2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/b5/52/708c93e51bb3e9b49dcdd9641e62fa5f1c60cf4172c0cf45567a2dece996/zipline-0.8.2.tar.gz#md5=2ddca99691409ebb8c85012ddbaecb19 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.8.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/c2/5a/0471cad4b5b392074c78622a782c2614b5c3bab68418ae3c4315031d12be/zipline-1.0.1.tar.gz#md5=645d7df6286b16466df5ed8225fd2dc7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 1.0.1
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/d5/34/f211a756945bc765dfeddb86d31b99b2992c123279a24c26cfd7d942575d/zipline-0.8.3-cp27-none-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=1c87ce91a7b559b14be657c164e78c87 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/d9/90/05ad3dc4e6fee0b890e5316113a2eea457a85928382ae7eacec346937f6c/zipline-0.6.1.tar.gz#md5=e07499447eccdfc97d57478daef4d114 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.6.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/dc/e0/341e3c5775201b998bd69a81c2b47cc2b40d09c56730163f4b6a9ef4336d/zipline-0.5.2.tar.gz#md5=a99e177d7aeb780b00884119069b2f36 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/df/ef/ffab7fc9bc6d4e833446a012421b470ff8c67f118a5efdbe0a593690aaa0/zipline-0.5.8.tar.gz#md5=512bb1ca2a13861c6128a852e627193f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/ec/98/e46201a8c0041112c67e7563bdd0d2c2f930f037f27cf157d1210406e0d2/zipline-0.9.0.tar.gz#md5=020494f647c8f5adab3a06ddb7e42dcc (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.9.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/ee/b4/c445d8b4821e8a170dc46de3d058ea07b0fdc3dedce4f9692ebca408ebb6/zipline-0.5.1.tar.gz#md5=2f91b1c1081a401cee28b6f8583da150 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 0.5.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/f3/42/449f570dca8b46edc0a65e35ce5543b6b4d1ee7b8bfebd06277b054442f7/zipline-1.0.0.tar.gz#md5=cc04ef77b46b631ea05b9953b9c6d587 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version: 1.0.0
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/95/9e/98e2f815f3dd4e8f49b48431f4fc9ff8336270a9c77f5da147cf05b346e1/zipline-0.7.0rc1.tar.gz#md5=5963340584c1bddd446c09bfbbedd38c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/), version 0.7.0rc1 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
  Using version 1.0.2 (newest of versions: 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.9.0, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.10, 0.5.9, 0.5.8, 0.5.7, 0.5.6, 0.5.5, 0.5.4, 0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.0)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/06/8e/8355df80f313706418ee9db3521c6f0578426d92b6dcddf396d58c4de2e6/zipline-1.0.2.tar.gz#md5=4c7958ad131ebbeeec7d4399bdeff12b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/zipline/)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/zipline/setup.py) egg_info for package zipline
    warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.

    Installed /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/zipline/Cython-0.24.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/zipline/setup.py", line 300, in <module>
        **conditional_arguments
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 264, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 620, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 852, in best_match
        dist = working_set.find(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 503, in find
        raise VersionConflict(dist,req)     # XXX add more info
    pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (numpy 1.8.2 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.9.2'))
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'

warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'

warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'

warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'

Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.



Installed /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/zipline/Cython-0.24.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/zipline/setup.py", line 300, in <module>

    **conditional_arguments

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__

    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 264, in fetch_build_eggs

    replace_conflicting=True

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 620, in resolve

    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 852, in best_match

    dist = working_set.find(req)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 503, in find

    raise VersionConflict(dist,req)     # XXX add more info

pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (numpy 1.8.2 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.9.2'))

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/zipline
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 326, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 715, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/zipline
```

Any suggestions, why it is not working?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended by `zipline`'s [documentation](http://www.zipline.io/install.html#installing-with-pip), this answer uses a virtualenv in which we use `pip` to install and manage `zipline` and its dependencies.

First, go to the terminal in your Cloud9 IDE to update the package lists and install the necessary [dependencies](http://www.zipline.io/install.html#gnu-linux) and `python-virtualenv`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev python-dev gfortran pkg-config libfreetype6-dev python-virtualenv
```

Note that `numpy` is required but unfortunately, the `python-numpy` package in the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories is too old for `zipline`, so we use `pip` instead to install `numpy`.

Now, create a virtualenv at your project directory, activate the virtualenv, upgrade `pip` and `setuptools`, and then install `numpy` and `zipline`:

```
virtualenv venv  # create a virtualenv called venv
source venv/bin/activate  # activate virtualenv
pip install -U pip setuptools  # upgrade pip and setuptools
pip install numpy  # install numpy
pip install zipline  # install zipline
```

The `pip` installation for `zipline` will take a while; please be patient. Once you are done working in the virtualenv, deactivate it by running:

```
deactivate
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Would you be so kind to extend your answer, how to run the first basic algorithm?

Comment: @mrquad Hmm, what do you mean by "first basic algorithm"?